# Is there any download link for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 32 bit?

Tags: 18.04, downloads, 32-bit

Is there a link to download a copy of the latest version of Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 32 bit?

Comment: Why 18.04.4 LTS? 18.04.5 LTS is newer and still supported. You find it via https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.5/ But I don't know if there is a 32-bit version.

Comment: You can probably use 32-bit ISO for Ubuntu MATE - https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/18.04/ubuntu-mate-18.04-desktop-i386.iso , https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/bionic/ubuntu-mate-18.04.4-desktop-i386.iso , https://releases.ubuntu-mate.org/archived/bionic/ubuntu-mate-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso .

Comment: You have a flag for 20.04 and ask in question about 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Ubuntu run well (including with wifi) on a 32-bit machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164278/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-run-well-including-with-wifi-on-a-32-bit-machine)

Answer (score 2):

There are no "official" download images for 32-bit architecture.

All official images of 18.04 (Bionic) are [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/release/), and supported architectures are:

- AMD64
- ARMv8 (64-bit)
- PPC64
- S390
- RasPi ARM-64
- RasPi ARM-HF

However, in the download archive, there are 32-bit images [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/).

Be aware though, this is totally unsupported in all aspects (and the HTTP connection is also insecure).

Answer (score 0):

no, AFAIK, Ubuntu stopped supporting 32-bit pc's since 18.04 (I could be wrong because I only follow LTS releases). Maybe you can compile Ubuntu from source and it would work then but I don't know how and if it would work.

Comment: Ubuntu still supported i386 in the *bionic* or 18.04 cycle; tehre was no Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS ISO, but other ISOs still remained (you could upgrade Ubuntu Desktop to 18.04 if you were using i386, or use another i386 ISO and install `ubuntu-desktop` to get a i386 desktop system; but the ISO for Ubuntu Desktop was longer offered (i386 with the GNOME desktop didn't make sense thus not provided it to me did make sense).  I continued QA-testing using i386 into the *disco* or 19.04 cycle when i386 was finally dropped  (installed i386 systems got upgrades until they reached EOL though)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 32-bit release of Ubuntu 18. However that does not mean it is not possible.

I did this recently, so I can sorta help. However, I cannot guarantee that it will work. I think this solution only works for x86_64 CPU with 32bit bios. You can check CPU characteristics with lscpu command. If you create the USB stick as normal with amd64 official iso and add the "bootia32.efi" in efi/boot then the 32bit bios can start it as live and even install. Sorry, if this solution does not help in your specific case.

here is the bootia32.efi I used (do not worry it works not only for Asus t100ta):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jfwells/linux-asus-t100ta/master/boot/bootia32.efi

Answer (score 0):

I have found (2021-09-01) an ISO for Ubuntu 18.04 32bit Studio at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/18.04/release/ .
I installed it, and it's GUI based. It seems designed for media artists, and I had to install gcc, make (etc) to do useful stuff.
ATM it seems acceptable for what I want to do.